# Connecting to a node.js socket.io server in another network with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I just created a working example chat programm with socket.io using express for setting up the server. Just like it is described on the socket.io webpage.

The Client Html File is sent to the client when connecting to the ip adress with a browser.

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
server = require("http").createServer(app),
io = require("socket.io").listen(server),
mongoose = require("mongoose"),
users = {};

server.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("Server erfolgreich initialisiert!");});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");});
```

But I want the Clients Index.html to connect to the server itself and not being send by the server side. With a HttpRequest as a handshake or anyhow.   I found nothing on the socket.io webpage and no working answer in here so I doubt that it is even possible. Or is the code I have already working and I only have to change something else?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you give an example? What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: My goal is to connect to my "server" by a script instead of writing the adress in a browser. I need it because my clients are mobile javascript applications and not just browser pages. Example: The Client started and I want it to connect to my websocket server. The Server isn´t in the network and I want to adress it by URL.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer!!! I actually just failed. I just got confused by some wrong information and some Bugs. A simple

```
var socket = io.connect("http://199.91.38.266:3000");
```

already worked. (random IP of course)

of course there must be the socket.io framework included:

```
<script src="http://199.91.38.266:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. I have the same issue. I use localhost:3000 on my file but it didn't work. Do I need to use a public ip?

Comment: You have to use your public ip. And i think you have to forward the ports your using.